# Facing issue in using file upload control in gridview

Tags: visual-web-developer

I am using gridview inside update panel with asp.net file upload control. But every time while uploading a file fileupload.Hasfile is always returning null . And on edit button click whole page is getting refreshed.

I need to use gridview inside Update panel.

Below is structure of my page.

First my page is loading and there are few tabs on page and on the click of one tab we are loading usercontrol(dynamically). That user control has gridview with file upload control in it. But due to Null value of has file we are unable to upload the document.

Please help!

Thanks!

Deepak

Answer (score 0):

```c#
HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
{
 HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];
 if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
 {
  string st1 = "<u>File #" + (i + 1) + "</u><br>";
  string st2 = "File Content Type: " + userPostedFile.ContentType + "<br>";
  string st3 = "File Size: " + userPostedFile.ContentLength + "kb<br>";
  string st4 = userPostedFile.FileName;
  userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));
 }
}
```